# ClassCastException on Cardlayout

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

I'm on that stage of learning Java where you get to make GUIs. For this program, I'm using CardLayout for swapping between panels. The problem is, I get this error over and over. I've searched everywhere and I still cannot solve it. The error as shown on console is:

> Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ClassCastException: class java.awt.FlowLayout cannot be cast to class java.awt.CardLayout (java.awt.FlowLayout and java.awt.CardLayout are in module java.desktop of loader 'bootstrap')

The console said my problem is on this part of the code:

```
public FrameMenuPrincipal() {
    initComponents();
    deffbg = new JPanel();
    deffbg.add(pane1, "panewelc");
    deffbg.add(pane2, idcreate);
    deffbg.add(pane3, idsite);
    
    cl = (CardLayout)(deffbg.getLayout());
    cl.show(deffbg, idmenu);
}
```

deffbg being the parent panel;

For adding more context, I've been using [this](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html) tutorial, and I'm programming in NetBeans, using the GUI builder.

Comment: The exception is telling you that your deffbg JPanel isn't using a CardLayout. So you will need to give it one if it is supposed to have one. Go to the source to see how to use it: [CardLayout Tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, JPanel used a FlowLayout. If you want to use something different, you can provide it in the constructor. So in this case, if you wanted to use a CardLayout you could instantiate it like this:

```
deffbg = new JPanel(new CardLayout());
```

Comment: god damn, i love you, thank u so much, i would give you an upvote, but im too new to the page

Comment: Generally, I would keep a reference to the `CardLayout` directly, this way you avoid the casting issue and keep the code cleaner - but that's me